# Swift - UINavigationBar is disappearing - Storyboard reference

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm havig this navigaton bar at the very beginning of my project, I'm hidding it at connection and then displaying it later on.
My sotryboard began to get huge so I've decided to put the parameters views of my app in a second storyboard.
The second storyboard begins with a view (that I'm displaying using "Presentr" library) which has already no access to the navigation bar from the first storyboard.

I think that the storyboard reference is somehow destroying my navigationController.
What am I doing wrong, and what should I do to correct it ?

Comment: Not quite clear... In your "main" storyboard, the NavBar is somehow disappearing? Or, you want the first VC in your second storyboard to be in a NavController?

Comment: I want the first VC of my second storyboard to have the navigationController

Comment: OK - I have no idea what "Presentr" library is... are you *pushing* the VC from storyboard-2 onto an existing NavController in storyboard-1?

Comment: Presentr allows you to display new VC in a custom way (for me, I'm displaying a VC as a SlideBar). | 

That's what I want. I would like my storyboard2 to know that there is already a navigationController in my storyboard1. But even in Xcode, in the storyboard2, the VCs inside it don't have the top navigation bar.

Comment: Still not quite clear.. Is this new VC going to be part of the NavController hierarchy? Or is it presented independent of the NavController? Is your goal to have the new VC's view to have a NavBar? Or to have the new VC's *top* to be at the bottom of the existing NavBar?

Comment: I want the VCs from storyboard2 to have the same hierarchy as if they were in the storyboard1. I only made 2 different storyboard so it'd be cleaner. I only want one navBar, the one set at the very beginning of the sotryboard1

Comment: OK - "NavController hierarchy" has nothing to do with "storyboard hierarchy". So, to try and clarify what you are asking about... ***IF*** the VC you want to use as a "SlideBar" was in the same storyboard, would you have a push segue to get to it? Or, would it not be connected to your NavigationController?

Comment: The main issue here is that, when i'm using another Storyboard, I'm losing my navigation controller :/

For example, if I keep all my VCs in the same storyboard, everything is as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was because of library "presentr". Somehow when I'm using this library to dsplay a VC (no matter how it's linked into the storyboard), the VC loses the hierarchy with the navigation controller.

Hope it'll help